# Не работает $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php

Надо взять адрес сайта с которого перешел пользователь, как я понял использовать надо $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], но он ничего не показывает, с какого бы сайта я не перешел.

```
$sub_id2 = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('<?echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>');
});
</script>
```

Выводит просто пустое сообщене

Comment: Может, у вас в браузере рефереры просто отключены?

Comment: И кстати в вашем коде потенциальная XSS-уязвимость

Comment: @andreymal мне не суть в безопасности, просто надо во всех возможных случаях получать адрес страницы с которой перешли

Comment: Проверьте в других имеющихся у вас браузерах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
он ничего не показывает, с какого бы сайта я не перешел.
```

А как вы переходите на сайт с любого сайта?

`HTTP_REFERER` может не записываться если вводят URL через адресную строку, или через закладки, или история отключена в браузере, попробуйте добавить к примеру ссылку на свой сайт через исходный код на любом сайте и проверьте или при переходе с другой страницы вашего сайта.

Comment: Спасибо, я пробовал отправить ссылку в чат, и по ней перейти, теперь же поставил ссылку в исходный код страницы и всё получилось

Comment: @shumik_UA а ну так чат не является «любым сайтом» :)

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть связано с редиректами на сайте - которые очень распространены во фреймворках. Например, все переходы перекидываются на  index.php, который весь запрос перекидывает ещё куда-то. Тут очень легко затеряться рефереру.